# Why does FPCA not use scaling as PCA?

Tags: time-series, pca, dimensionality-reduction, high-dimensional, functional-data-analysis

Functional principal component analysis (FPCA), according to the original paper, does not use scaling before FPCA, as in PCA. Instead, it uses a covariance matrix to compute the eigen-components.

I just don't get it. Is it supposed to be better to use scaling before FPCA?

Related question: [Functional principal component analysis (FPCA): what is it all about?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/23566/functional-principal-component-analysis-fpca-what-is-it-all-about)